# pyspark kafka submit failed

Tags: python, pyspark, apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api

i am using pyspark to consume data on kafka, I type this on my console to submit :

```
spark-submit --jars /Users/alexsun/spark-streaming-kafka-0-8-assembly_2.11-2.2.0.jar comsumer.py
```

where consumer.py is my python program, then in the console, it raises:

```
    ________________________________________________________________________________________________

  Spark Streaming's Kafka libraries not found in class path. Try one of the following.

  1. Include the Kafka library and its dependencies with in the
     spark-submit command as

     $ bin/spark-submit --packages org.apache.spark:spark-streaming-kafka-0-8:2.2.0 ...

  2. Download the JAR of the artifact from Maven Central http://search.maven.org/,
     Group Id = org.apache.spark, Artifact Id = spark-streaming-kafka-0-8-assembly, Version = 2.2.0.
     Then, include the jar in the spark-submit command as

     $ bin/spark-submit --jars <spark-streaming-kafka-0-8-assembly.jar> ...

________________________________________________________________________________________________


Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/alexsun/PycharmProjects/untitled/spark_kafka/comsumer.py", line 51, in <module>
    main()
  File "/Users/alexsun/PycharmProjects/untitled/spark_kafka/comsumer.py", line 45, in main
    main_main(ssc)
  File "/Users/alexsun/PycharmProjects/untitled/spark_kafka/comsumer.py", line 29, in main_main
    consumer = KafkaUtils.createStream(ssc, zookeeper, groupid, {kafkatopic: 1})
  File "/Users/alexsun/binSoftware/spark-2.2.0-bin-hadoop2.7/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/streaming/kafka.py", line 69, in createStream
  File "/Users/alexsun/binSoftware/spark-2.2.0-bin-hadoop2.7/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/streaming/kafka.py", line 195, in _get_helper
```

it seems tell me that I has not point the path of jar file, but I looked at the log info, it has:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lwz9M.png)

```
    18/01/27 19:46:59 INFO SparkContext: Added JAR file:/Users/alexsun/spark-streaming-kafka-0-8-assembly_2.11-2.2.0.jar at spark://192.168.1.150:57342/jars/spark-streaming-kafka-0-8-assembly_2.11-2.2.0.jar with timestamp 1517053619142
18/01/27 19:46:59 INFO SparkContext: Added file file:/Users/alexsun/PycharmProjects/untitled/spark_kafka/consumer.py at file:/Users/alexsun/PycharmProjects/untitled/spark_kafka/consumer.py with timestamp 1517053619150
```

I am sure the jar file is there, so why this exception there?

I don't know what the problem is, can you help me out?

Answer (score 1):

It's corresponding to the version of the pyspark, you must make sure this

```
spark-submit --jars /Users/alexsun/spark-streaming-kafka-0-8-assembly_2.11-2.2.0.jar comsumer.pynter code here
```

at the

```
spark-streaming-kafka-0-8-assembly_2.11-2.2.0.jarenter code here
```

must use the same pyspark version, in this case you're using `pyspark=2.2.0`

Another things, I encounter this problem too, but I encounter it when I try it with `--packages` maybe you can consider to use

```
--packages org.apache.spark:spark-streaming-kafka-0-8_2.11:{version of pyspark}
```

instead of the `--jar` option